# Simplify : $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{6 + \sqrt{3}}} - \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{6 + \sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: irrational-numbers

My exams are approaching fast and this question was in one of the sample papers .

I have to simplify  $$\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{6 + \sqrt{3}}} - \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{6 + \sqrt{2}}}$$

I am a ninth grader and we have been taught how to rationalize the denominator but I have no idea how I could simplify this one where there is a root of a root . Even my math teacher couldn't do it and said that she'll have to check it out .

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{6-\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{36-2} = \sqrt{34}$

Comment: @Mayank, by any chance, you meant $\sqrt6+\sqrt3$ not $\sqrt{6+\sqrt3}$

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for pointing that out , I am new here so don't know all the rules , I'll take care of this from next time .

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No , That is  why I had a problem with the question . I could solve it if it was $\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{3}$ .

Answer (score 1):

Things look pretty nice, if the problem is

$$\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}+\frac{3\sqrt2}{\sqrt6+\sqrt3}-\frac{4\sqrt3}{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}$$

Multiplying each term with the conjugate of the respective numerator we get,

$$\frac{\sqrt6(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)}{3-2}+\frac{3\sqrt2(\sqrt6+\sqrt3)}{6-3}-\frac{4\sqrt3(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)}{6-2}$$
$$(\text{ as } (\sqrt3-\sqrt2)(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)=(\sqrt3)^2-(\sqrt2)^2=3-2\text{  and so on} )$$

$$=\sqrt6(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+\sqrt2(\sqrt6+\sqrt3)-\sqrt3(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)$$

$$=\sqrt{18}-\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{12}-\sqrt6-\sqrt{18}+\sqrt6=0$$

Comment: Exactly ! But I'm afraid that is not the case :( 
Thanks for answering .

Comment: I think this is the identity which is meant. It is much more "beautiful" than the one above.

Comment: Yeah , maybe it is . This is also the identity that has been taught to us. Maybe it's a misprint .